# vba replacing one line of code with two line of codes

Tags: vba, ms-access, office365, ms-access-2010, ms-access-2016

I have this line of code in vba currently:

```
Set conn = CurrentProject.Connection
```

I would like to do a global replacement in current project with

```
conn.ConnectionString =extractConnectionStringADOfromOLE
conn.OPEN
```

how can i do that using ms-access find and replace tool?

notice: i need to know how vba inserts a line break in the code or another way of doing the replacement.

thanks!

I tried using readable line breaks but the compiler produce errors on the new lines

Comment: I don't think it's possible using the replace tool. Either auto-replace and correct the errors or replace by hand to avoid corruption.

Comment: You could replace the line with `conn.ConnectionString =extractConnectionStringADOfromOLE : conn.OPEN`. The `:` will separate 2 statements on one line. Looks ugly, but works.